# changing the color scale on ggmap map and removing the google label

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

The code below produces  this  choropleth map according to some metric .

```
map <- get_map(location = 'Europe', zoom=4)
m0 <- ggmap(map,extent="device")
m1 <- m0 + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=PERC), data=eurAccAtWorkMapDf, alpha=0.5)
m2 <- m1 + geom_path(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), data=eurAccAtWorkMapDf, color='black')
m2
```

[image]
There is no need to demonstrate a reproducible example as my question is of  a different nature. As my project is a eurostat project , i need to use specific colors that eurostat has set as default . 
[image]
In the screenshot above i want to use final line's  palette (PM 302). I'm trying to find the hexadecimal code of the first and last color and set the scale range between these , though i cant find the codes  nor can i set the correct function(`scale_color_gradient(low="",high="",guide="legend"`) does nothing.

Furthermore , i want to remove the google labels that appear in the bottom of the map . I don't know if this is even possible , though if someone knows anything about it ...

Comment: Even if removing the google label is possible, would it be legal?

Comment: haha i don't know but it's a fact that i can't have a company's name on the map . I could adjust the ylim  of the map but that would erase  2 countries ( malta and cyprus ) and that's pretty bad . I could also use  zoom=3 on the get_map function but that would zoom out  to a point that degrades my map a lot .

Comment: Well, you can't use google's maps without their credit.  http://www.google.co.uk/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html although removing the credit from the map but displaying it elsewhere on the web page seems acceptable.

Comment: whoa , that would be great if i could move the bottom labels to be on top and then truncate the map . Anyone knows of the needed  parameter?